# Search a String for Alpha Numeric Characters in a Pattern

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching, alpha, numeric

I have a string that contains 5 words. In the string one of the words is a Ham Radio Call Sign and can be anyone of the thousands of call signs in the US. In order to extract the Call Sign from the string I need to utilize the below pattern. The Call Sign I need to extract can be in any of the 5 positions in the string. The number is never the first character and the number is never the last character. The string is actually put together from an Array since it is originally read from a text file.

```
$string = $word[1] $word[2] $word[3] etc....
```

So the search can be either done on the whole string or each piece of the array.

```
Patterns:
1 Number and 3 Letters Example: AB4C A4BC
1 Number and 4 Letters Example: A4BCD
1 Number and 5 Letters Example: AB4CDE
```

I have tried everything I can think of and search till I cant search no more. I am sure I am over thinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-step regular expression like this would do it:

```
$str = "hello A4AB there BC5AD";
$signs = array();
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][A-Z\d]{1,3}[A-Z]/', $str, $possible_signs);
foreach($possible_signs[0] as $possible_sign)
    if (preg_match('/^\D+\d\D+$/', $possible_sign))
        array_push($signs, $possible_sign);

print_r($signs); //Array ([0] => A4AB [1] => BC5AD)
```

**Explanation**

This is a regular expression approach, using two patterns. I don't *think* it could be done with one and still satisfy the exact requirements of the matching rules.

The first pattern enforces the following requirements:

- substring starts and ends with a capital letter
- substring contains only other capital letters or numbers between the first and last letter
- substring is, overall, not more than 6 characters long

What I *can't* do in that same pattern, for complex REGEX reasons I won't go into (unless someone knows a way and can correct me), is enforce that only one number is contained.

@jeroen's answer *does* enforce this in a single pattern, but in turn does *not* enforce the correct length of the substring. Either way, we need a second pattern.

So after grabbing the initial matches, we loop over the results. We then apply each to a second pattern that enforces simply that there is only *one* number in the substring.

If so, we green-light the substring and it's added to the `$signs` array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont not uderstand what you wrote but I know one thing it works..... I had to change the 1,3 to 1,4. If Call Sign KD6ABC was in the string it would return KD6AB. Do you think it will mess things up later? I tried with 4 different calls so far and perfect. I will dissect this so I fully understand it but thanks a million I owe u a beer......

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile for explaining it, or should I say Thank you for going the extra Kilometer....... cheers.....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the other words can contain, but you could use a regular expression like:

```
#\b[a-z]+\d[a-z]+\b#i
                    ^ case insensitive
                 ^^ a word boundary
           ^^^^^^ One or more letters
         ^^ One number
```

You can make it more restrictive by using `{1,3}` instead of `+` for the letters so that you have a sequence of 1 to 3 letters.

The complete expression would be something like:

```
$success = preg_match('#\b[a-z]+\d[a-z]+\b#i', $input_string, $matches);
```

where `$matches[0]` will contain the matched value, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).